# Use of undeclared type 'DKAsset', Use of unresolved identifier 'DKImagePickerController'?

Tags: swift, xcode7

I want to select multiple images from gallery. so for that I have installed DKImagePikerController Using pod.

For that in podfile.

pod 'DKImagePickerController'
 use_frameworks!

After that I have followed their demo example for implement gallery in app.
but I got follwoing error.

1.Use of undeclared type 'DKAsset'.
2.Use of unresolved identifier 'DKImagePickerController'?

I am following this lib and code.
https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to import framework. for that,

import DKImagePickerController

after that under Navigator>select pods>Build Settings>Architectures>Build Active Architecture Only -> Set to No for all pods.(select all pods listed under "Target" and set "No" for "Build Active Architecture Only")

Clean and build your project and you are done.