# demo for DKImagePickerController

Tags: swift, swift3

I am developing a collage app, for that i am using `DKImagePickerController` to select multiple images at a time. Github link for `pod` is https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController

I am following the documentation and getting an error-

> Use of undeclared type 'DKAssets'

on stackoverflow i got this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270303/use-of-undeclared-type-dkasset-use-of-unresolved-identifier-dkimagepickercon for the same question, but that didn't help me.

Comment: Have you add library by pods or manually? can you share some sceenshots of code that you trying?

Comment: I have added library by pods. I just followed github documentation and at starting with few lines i am getting this error.

Comment: request to share some line of code?

Comment: on click of a button, I just added these lines-  
`let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()`  
` pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets:[DKAssets]) in`  
` debugPrint(assets)`  
 `  }`  
` self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)`  

and in starting `import DKImagePickerController`

Comment: i think you make mistake in installing a pods. Open your pod file and make sure you have to add "pod 'DKImagePickerController' this line after use FrameWork line. and again install pod

Comment: I did the same but getting this error.

Comment: make deep clean your project by command + Shift + K

Comment: already did. :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
 let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()

    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
      print("didSelectAssets")
      print(assets)
    }

    self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```